# Heartbleed RSA Key

Tags: heartbleed

I'm currently a student doing some research into the Heartbleed Vulnerability and I'm having difficulty retrieving the correct RSA private keys.

Here is my setup environment in VirtualBox:

1. Kali Linux 2.0 Host Only Network with ip address 192.168.2.200/24
2. Turnkey OpenLDAP Server Host Only Network with ip address 192.168.2.202/24

The openLDAP server is using OpenSSL version 1.0.1e and I have managed to get usernames and passwords of users when they login using HTTPS.

However in my Kali 2.0 when I run the heartleech program

```
root@kali~#heartleech 192.168.2.202 -a
```

it returns an RSA private key. I then run Wireshark to generate some traffic (logging in and out as a user in the web browser https://192.168.2.202) I manage to get an encrypted alert and when I add the RSA key that heartleech produced it still does not decrypt the traffic.

What I was wondering is, where do you suppose this key is being generated from? As I cannot find this key on my OpenLDAP Server, any suggestions or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are really asking where could an RSA key come from in a OpenLDAP server?

Answer (score 3):

## Forward secrecy?

After the fact decryption will not work if client and server have negotiated a forward secure cipher suite. (Anything with DHE or ECDHE in the name.)

Check with WireShark. Selected suite name is in clear text.

## Does key match cert?

Check if [key and cert belong together](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73127/how-can-you-check-if-a-private-key-and-certificate-match-in-openssl-with-ecdsa).